# What should I look for in an antenna for a DVBT Dongle used for SDR?

Tags: antenna, rtl-sdr

I use a cheap DVBT dongle that I control via RTL-SDR. Right now a very basic setup. The general consensus seems to be that a long usb cable should be used (to keep noise from the computer away from the dongle) and the antenna directly plugged into the dongle (without cable, or a short one, is this because ogf grounding?).

The antenna is only a simply telescoping piece of metal. Using an amplifying antenna that I got my hands on, the reception was better, with the simple antenna I practically only pick up noise. Now I want to have a better reception without spending much money - what should I look for? I want to be able to listen to radio standard radio stations, but also to to use it as a scanner, so I'll probably be looking for a broadband antenna.

The dongle was built for TV, do TV and RF antennas have the same connections?

**Edit to add**
I have a dongle with a PAL-connector, not an F connector (from comparing with pictures)

Comment: who said 'dongle'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of broadband receiving antennas marketed specifically as [scanner antennas](https://www.google.com/search?q=scanner%20antenna).  Without more information on what attributes you specifically need, though, I can't recommend any specific antennas.

Without a picture of the connector, it will be hard to tell you what kind of adaptor to get, but it's unlikely to be a BNC connector, which is the most common type for these types of antennas.  Consider posting a new question with an image of the connector and adapter recommendations.

There are a number of PAL to BNC connectors available from many online sources:

[image]

Comment: AFAIK many/most of the dongles that have TV connectors have European-style Belling-Lee ("PAL") connectors, not US-style F connectors. Adapters are also available but are not the same.

Comment: Ah, I missed that it was a DVBT dongle, you're probably right.

Comment: Yes, it's a PAL connector.

Comment: Note that there's also a miniature bellings-lee (PAL) connector that might have been used in the dongle.  I don't see easy sources for adapters for those, but image they exist if you have such a connector.